# TeamCity agent: how to install yarn in Docker image

Tags: docker, teamcity, yarnpkg

I have downloaded a [TeamCity agent](https://hub.docker.com/r/jetbrains/teamcity-agent/) as a docker file onto my local machine. After a lot of fiddling, I finally got it running!

However, the builds in TeamCity are failing because the agent is complaining that it cannot find `yarn`. I have tried to install it using the following command:

```
docker exec d9 curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

However, it still can't find it and continues to complain. I have no idea where in the docker image `yarn` has been installed so I cannot edit the `$PATH` to add it. Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If the install happened correctly, yarn should exist here:

```
/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global
```

The docs say that the image is Ubuntu, (which I assume you are using a linux container).  Have you tried opening the bash prompt in the container and running:

```
curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt update && sudo apt install yarn
```

That should put yarn in your path, you can always commit the container afterwards to have it saved in the container.